# Did we have a gender before we were born?

Tags: soul, life

There's [another post that talks about something similar](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37685/does-a-soul-have-a-gender) but I could not get the answer to whether we were males and females before we were assigned bodies and sent into this world.

We do see references to us being husbands and wives in Paradise, so that means that the gender from this world will somehow continue in the afterlife, but my question is more about the life *before* this life.

Answer (score 1):

There is some evidence in below Hadith. Allah knows best. From the offspring of Adam we can see that Prophet David was of male gender.

> Messenger of Allāh (ﷺ) said: “When Allāh created Ādam He wiped his
> back and every person that He created among his offspring until the
> Day of Resurrection fell out of his back. He placed a ray of light
> between the eyes of every person. Then He showed them to Ādam and he
> said: ‘O Lord! Who are these people?’ He said: ‘These are your
> offspring.’ He saw one of them whose ray between his eyes amazed him,
> so he said: ‘O Lord! Who is this?’ He said: ‘**This is a man from the
> latter nations of your offspring called Dawud**.’ He said: ‘Lord! How
> long did You make his lifespan?’ He said: ‘Sixty years.’ He said: ‘O
> Lord! Add forty years from my life to his.’ So at the end of Ādam’s
> life, the Angel of death of came to him, and he said: ‘Do I not have
> forty years remaining?’ He said: ‘Did you not give them to your son
> Dawud?'” He said: “Ādam denied, so his offspring denied, and Ādam
> forgot and his offspring forgot, and Ādam erred, so his offspring
> erred.” (At-Tirmidhee no. 3356)